Focus on the search input field whenever showSearch state is true
I have a problem trying to focus on the input field whenever a state showSearch state is true. I am using useRef and useEffect to achieve this. So, whenever showSearch flag changes, i run useEffect hook which checks if showSearch is true and if it is, then it focuses to the HTML element references using useRef. However, there is something wrong with it because it does not run.
here is the code snippet.
const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);
const searchInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(showSearch);
    console.log(searchInputRef);

    if (showSearch && searchInputRef.current){
      searchInputRef.current.focus();
    }}, [showSearch]);



<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
                  <InputGroup size="lg">
                    <Input
                      variant="flushed"
                      placeholder="Search"
                      _placeholder={{
                        opacity: 1,
                        color: "gray.500",`your text`
                        fontSize: "1.5rem",
                      }}
                      _focus={{ borderColor: "whiteAlpha.800" }}
                      borderColor="#FFFFFF80"
                      pb={"1rem"}
                      fontSize="2rem"
                      onChange={handleSearchChange}
                      value={searchText}
                      ref={searchInputRef}.  // this is where i have referenced the HTML element.
                    />
                    <InputRightElement
                      w={["45%", "20%"]}
                      justifyContent={"flex-end"}
                    >
                      {searchText.length > 0 && (
                        <Button
                          size="sm"
                          onClick={handleClear}
                          bg={"transparent"}
                          color={"white"}
                          fontSize={"1.1rem"}
                          _hover={{ bg: "transparent" }}
                        >
                          Clear
                        </Button>
                      )}
                    </InputRightElement>
                  </InputGroup>
                </form>

Let me know if you need more information on it.
Also, I am using chakra ui for react components.
Tried using UseRef and useEffect so everytime a state flag is true, the focus is changed to the desired input element.

the input component you’re using might not be fully rendered, this can happen if showSearch triggers a new render, but the effect runs before the input is rendered
you can wrap the focus logic in a setTimeout, to ensure the input components is focused after the rendering is complete
const SearchForm = () => {
  const [showSearch, setShowSearch] = useState(false);
  const searchInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (showSearch) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (searchInputRef.current) {
          searchInputRef.current.focus();
        }
      }, 0);
    }
  }, [showSearch]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <InputGroup size="lg">
        <Input
          variant="flushed"
          placeholder="Search"
          _placeholder={{
            opacity: 1,
            color: "gray.500",
            fontSize: "1.5rem",
          }}
          _focus={{ borderColor: "whiteAlpha.800" }}
          borderColor="#FFFFFF80"
          pb={"1rem"}
          fontSize="2rem"
          onChange={handleSearchChange}
          value={searchText}
          ref={searchInputRef}
        />
        <InputRightElement
          w={["45%", "20%"]}
          justifyContent={"flex-end"}
        >
          {searchText.length > 0 && (
            <Button
              size="sm"
              onClick={handleClear}
              bg={"transparent"}
              color={"white"}
              fontSize={"1.1rem"}
              _hover={{ bg: "transparent" }}
            >
              Clear
            </Button>
          )}
        </InputRightElement>
      </InputGroup>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SearchForm;

if you don't want to use setTimeout, here is more reliable solution:
use useLayoutEffect instead of useEffect, it runs synchronously after all DOM mutations but before the browser draws the components
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  if (showSearch && searchInputRef.current) {
    searchInputRef.current.focus();
  }
}, [showSearch]);

